# IdentityServer4: "code challenge required" under hybrid flow

Tags: identityserver4, windows-authentication

I have a MVC client accessing a web API protected by IDS4 server. It works perfectly when I use ResponseType = "code". But when I change it to ResponseType = "code id_token" (hybrid flow), I start to get this "Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request code challenge required" error.

Here is my client configuration on the IDS4 side:

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials, 
            RequirePkce = false,
            //AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:6009/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:6009/signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "roles",
                "MyAPI"
            }
```

And here is the configuration on the MVC Client side. Note that it is the 'options.ResponseType = "code id_token"' that made the error occur. It will not error if I use "code" instead.

```
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:6005";
        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        //options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("roles");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.Scope.Add("MyAPI");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        };
    });
```

And here is what's in the log:

```
[2021-03-12T15:25:51.014Z] [4] [Error] Request validation failed 
[2021-03-12T15:25:51.013Z] [4] [Error] code_challenge is missing
{
  "ClientId": "mvc",
  "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:6009/signin-oidc",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:6009/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token",
  "ResponseMode": "fragment",
  "GrantType": "hybrid",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "State": "CfDJ....8oxh4",
  "PromptMode": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "mvc",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:6009/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile email roles MyAPIoffline_access",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "637511...lOGNh",
    "state": "CfDJ8...8oxh4",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
    "x-client-ver": "5.5.0.0"
  }
}
```

By the way, I am testing hybrid flow because I am trying to make the Windows authentication working under IDS4. My local login works but not Windows. Some resource says that hybrid flow is needed for that. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that IdentityServer always requires PKCE and that's why it complains when you don't provide the necessary challenge.

Dominic writes [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/5181#issuecomment-793462947):

> ```
> Code flow without PKCE is vulnerable to code injection attacks. That's why we do not expose it.
> ```

Adding the code challenge/verifier in a client is not that complicated.

Here's how I present OAuth 2.1 in my training classes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tore Nestenius! Please excuse my ignorance but I thought PKCE is only needed with public clients, like mobile devices, not MVC. Plus, it works fine with my MVC client if I just do ...ResponseType = "code". Could you point me to the right direction on how to add code challenge/verifier on the client? I would like to give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: With latest OAuth 2.1, the recommendation is to always use PKCE with the code flow. Why do you need the hybrid flow? What kind of client do you have that does not support PKCE? ASP.NET Core MVC have that built in. Today you should try to only use the authorization code flow or client credentials flow for machine-to-machine setups.

Comment: Thanks again Tore Nestenius! That's good to know! I am not sure if I really need hybrid flow - I just want to get the Windows authentication to work and somebody suggested I need that. I know my original question wasn't about this, but my real issue is that my Windows authentication seems running in a loop - the browser's Windows login screen keeps coming back after submit without any error.

Comment: Here is the article (https://damienbod.com/2018/04/15/supporting-both-local-and-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-identityserver4/) seems to suggest that I need hybrid flow to get both local and Windows login to work for MVC.

Comment: see https://oauth.net/2.1/  and also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1lgyU3CKI8&ab_channel=OktaDev   Arraon is one of the authors of OAuth 2.1, so its a good show he has about OAuth.

Comment: I have not real experience mixing OAuth and Windows auth. But I doubt that hybrid flow is required to achieve that.. But the question is if you should not do the Windows auth inside IdentityServer directly, instead of doing it in the client? see http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

Comment: What I am planning to do is to implement an identity gateway that consolidates different IDPs including Windows, local account and other external providers. That will give me ability to not only authenticate user, but provision access by adding claims to JWT based on different IDPs. In my limited knowledge about IDS4, I thought it would be easier to achieve that if I do the Windows auth from IDS4. Am I wrong on that? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for the oath 2.1 references by the way. It is very helpful.

Comment: added picture how I present OAuth 2.1 in my OAuth training classes, does this make the answer acceptable?

Comment: Thanks again Tore Nestenius! and I have accepted your answer. I will post another question focusing on my Windows authentication looping issue. Please chime in if you can shed light on it. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck with that :-)